# Is there any way to get event when a blue screen error show up?

Tags: c#

I know the pc will automatically restart after a few seconds (depending on configuration).

And yet is there any way to get an event of the blue screen while it happens ?

Comment: When a blue screen happens, the kernel basically shuts down, so your application won't be running.

Comment: You might be able to extract some information after the fact from the event log, but AFAIK this is as far as it gets

Comment: Exactly. When a blue screen occurs, there's no more programs, no more operating system. There's just the computer, and your frustration. But tell me, is this problem reproducible? I mean, does it always happen at the same point in the program's execution?

Comment: Mr Lister , I had a blue screen once this morning im not sure why. My idea was to make a program that will take for me automatic screenshot of the blue screen. Just a second before the computer restart it will take a screenshot of the blue screen. But i guess thats not possible.

Comment: [Blue Screen of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) it says `(which caused the computer to hang without any possibility of recovery, requiring a manual restart).`..so like @Hassan said your application wont be running

Comment: @user1363119 You can disable the automatic restart IIRC, and if it happens again, take a photograph.

Comment: You haven't told us what version of windows you are using, but the dump file is your best recourse for information about a bsod : http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/01/08/understanding-crash-dump-files.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible as people said,

You can still use these programs to analyze your BSODs

- [Whocrashed](http://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed)
- [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)